# setting up Jasmine + Webdriver - "cannot use import outside a module"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, webdriver, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I'm trying to set up a basic automated test in the browser against a react app, using webdriver and Jasmine. I'm using page object models to describe my app under test, like so:

[Example page object from JasmineBDD](https://github.com/amiya-pattnaik/webdriverIO-with-jasmineBDD/blob/master/test/pageobjects/ta-login.page.js)

I'm running Jasmine fine, and slurping up the spec. However after the browser spawns, I get a module error

```
import { SplashScreen } from './page_models/splash_screen.page'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I'm initiating the test with a local call to wdio, `node node_modules/.bin/wdio ./spec/support/wdio.conf.js` . How do I run my Jasmine spec code in an environment so that it's inside a module context ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, Can you confirm whether you are using `Babel` transcompiler and it is properly set it up?

Comment: @Naveen I bet it is not correctly set up. I will study :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to call `babel/register` in my jasmine config like so:

```
   beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
      require('@babel/register');
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 import/export not supported in nodejs version < 13 . You need to use legacy `require`, or use Babel/Typescript to transform your code from import/export to old syntax.

In nodejs 13+ you can enable ES6 import/export support. This is untested, so might be some underwater rocks. But you can try:
https://medium.com/@nodejs/announcing-core-node-js-support-for-ecmascript-modules-c5d6dc29b663